# Excel: How to add nested function inside sum?

Tags: excel

If this is my workbook:

```
A   B
1   6
2   5
3   4
```

I want to calculate (1-6)+(2-5)+(3-4) = -9. How can I sum the difference of two columns without creating a new column to store the differences first? I want something like =sum(A1:A3-B1:B3), but it's not correct. So what else might work?

Comment: The idea you have is correct, you just have to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER when you enter the formula.  This is called an array formula.  Google array formulas for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an array formula:

`{=SUM($A1:$A3-$B1:$B3)}`

Just write the formula without the brackets, then press control-shift-enter.

Answer (score 4):

If this is what you need, you can simply subtract the sums :

`=SUM(A1:A3) - SUM(B1:B3)`

Comment: No need to overcomplicate things! Definitely the simplest solution.